Page Reload Cart Contents not Updating for E-Commerce Website
so I am creating an E-commerce website. I'm not sure whats wrong with my javascript but when I add an item to the cart and then go to a different page its not update the contents in the cart or the span number that demonstrates the number of items in the cart unless the user manually refreshes the browser which is a nuisance.
I tried changing my code a lot and after hours of trying I still haven't fixed this issue. I have played around mainly with the functions related to Local Storage in my code. This is my javascript. I know its kind of a lot but I would really appreciate the help
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const addToCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.addcart');
    const subtotalElement = document.querySelector('.totalamt h4');
    const cartCountElement = document.querySelector('#order-icon span');
    const popoutCart = document.querySelector('#popout-cart');
    const overlay = document.querySelector('#overlay');


    document.querySelectorAll('.item-type').forEach(select => {
        select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            const selectedOption = event.target.selectedOptions[0];
            const unitPrice = parseFloat(selectedOption.getAttribute('data-price'));
            const parentItem = event.target.closest('.item-text-container');
            const priceElement = parentItem.querySelector('h4');
            if (priceElement) {
                priceElement.textContent = `$${unitPrice.toFixed(2)}`;
            }
        });
    });

    function updateCart(item) {
        const minusButton = item.querySelector('.minus');
        const plusButton = item.querySelector('.plus');
        const quantityElement = item.querySelector('.quantity');
        const cartTotalElement = item.querySelector('.carttotal');
        const unitPriceElement = item.querySelector('.unit-price');
        let unitPrice = parseFloat(unitPriceElement.textContent.replace('$', ''));

        function updateQuantity(change) {
            let quantity = parseInt(quantityElement.textContent) + change;
            if (quantity <= 0) {
                item.remove();
                updateSubtotal();
                updateCartCount();
                updateLocalStorage();
                return;
            }
            quantityElement.textContent = quantity;
            cartTotalElement.textContent = `$${(unitPrice * quantity).toFixed(2)}`;
            updateSubtotal();
            updateCartCount();
            updateLocalStorage();
        }

        minusButton.addEventListener('click', () => updateQuantity(-1));
        plusButton.addEventListener('click', () => updateQuantity(1));

        const showNoteLink = item.querySelector('.show-note');
        if (showNoteLink) {
            showNoteLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const noteParagraph = item.querySelector('.note');
                if (noteParagraph) {
                    noteParagraph.style.display = noteParagraph.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
                    showNoteLink.textContent = noteParagraph.style.display === 'none' ? 'Show Note' : 'Hide Note';
                }
            });
        }
    }

    addToCartButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const parentItem = button.closest('.item-text-container');
            const productName = parentItem.querySelector('h2').innerText;
            const selectedColor = parentItem.querySelector('#color')?.value || 'N/A';
            const selectedSize = parentItem.querySelector('#size')?.value ? parentItem.querySelector('#size').value + ' in' : 'N/A';
            const selectedTypeElement = parentItem.querySelector('#type');
            const selectedType = selectedTypeElement ? selectedTypeElement.value : 'N/A';
            const customNote = parentItem.querySelector('#note')?.value || 'N/A';
            const unitPriceElement = parentItem.querySelector('h4');

            let unitPrice = 0;
            if (unitPriceElement) {
                unitPrice = parseFloat(unitPriceElement.textContent.replace('$', ''));
            } else if (selectedTypeElement && selectedTypeElement.tagName === 'SELECT') {
                const selectedOption = selectedTypeElement.selectedOptions[0];
                unitPrice = parseFloat(selectedOption.getAttribute('data-price')) || 0;
            }

            const firstImageSrc = document.querySelector('#main-carousel .splide__slide img')?.src || '';

            let cartItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cartlist')).find(item =>
                item.querySelector('.cartname').textContent.trim() === productName
            );
            if (cartItem) {
                console.log('Item already in cart');
                const quantityElement = cartItem.parentNode.querySelector('.quantity');
                const cartTotalElement = cartItem.parentNode.querySelector('.carttotal');
                const quantity = parseInt(quantityElement.textContent) + 1;
                quantityElement.textContent = quantity;
                cartTotalElement.textContent = `$${(unitPrice * quantity).toFixed(2)}`;
                updateSubtotal();
                updateCartCount();
                updateLocalStorage();
            } else {
                console.log('Adding new item to cart');
                const cartItem = document.createElement('div');
                cartItem.classList.add('cartlist');
                cartItem.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="cartimg">
                        <img src="${firstImageSrc}" alt="${productName}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="cartdetails">
                        <div class="cartname">${productName}</div>
                        <div class="item-description">
                            ${selectedColor !== 'N/A' ? `<p class="color">${selectedColor}</p>` : ''}
                            ${selectedSize !== 'N/A' ? `<p class="size">${selectedSize}</p>` : ''}
                            ${selectedType !== 'N/A' ? `<p class="type">Type: ${selectedType}</p>` : ''}
                            ${customNote !== 'N/A' ? `
                                <a href="#" class="show-note">Show Note</a>
                                <p class="note" style="display: none;">${customNote}</p>
                            ` : ''}
                        </div>
                        <div class="cartquantity">
                            <span class="minus">&lt;</span>
                            <span class="quantity">1</span>
                            <span class="plus">&gt;</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carttotal" data-unit-price="${unitPrice.toFixed(2)}">$${unitPrice.toFixed(2)}</div>
                    <div class="unit-price" style="display: none;">$${unitPrice.toFixed(2)}</div>
                `;

                const cartContainer = document.querySelector('#popout-cart .carttab');
                if (cartContainer) {
                    cartContainer.appendChild(cartItem);
                }

                updateCart(cartItem);
                updateSubtotal();
                updateCartCount();
                updateLocalStorage();

                popoutCart.classList.add('show');
                overlay.classList.add('show');
            }
        });
    });

    function updateSubtotal() {
        let subtotal = 0;
        document.querySelectorAll('.carttotal').forEach(cartTotalElement => {
            subtotal += parseFloat(cartTotalElement.textContent.replace('$', ''));
        });
        subtotalElement.textContent = `$${subtotal.toFixed(2)} USD`;
    }

    function updateCartCount() {
        let totalItems = 0;
        document.querySelectorAll('.cartlist').forEach(cartItem => {
            const quantity = parseInt(cartItem.querySelector('.quantity').textContent);
            totalItems += quantity;
        });
        cartCountElement.textContent = totalItems;
    }

    function updateLocalStorage() {
        const cartItems = [];
        document.querySelectorAll('.cartlist').forEach(cartItem => {
            const productName = cartItem.querySelector('.cartname').textContent;
            const selectedColor = cartItem.querySelector('.item-description .color')?.textContent || '';
            const selectedSize = cartItem.querySelector('.item-description .size')?.textContent || '';
            const selectedType = cartItem.querySelector('.item-description .type')?.textContent || '';
            const customNote = cartItem.querySelector('.item-description .note')?.textContent || '';
            const unitPrice = parseFloat(cartItem.querySelector('.carttotal').getAttribute('data-unit-price'));
            const quantity = parseInt(cartItem.querySelector('.quantity').textContent, 10);
            const firstImageSrc = cartItem.querySelector('.cartimg img')?.src || '';

            cartItems.push({
                productName,
                selectedColor,
                selectedSize,
                selectedType,
                customNote,
                unitPrice,
                quantity,
                firstImageSrc
            });
        });

        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
    }


    function loadCartFromLocalStorage() {
        const cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];

        // Clear existing cart items
        const cartContainer = document.querySelector('#popout-cart .carttab');
        if (cartContainer) {
            cartContainer.innerHTML = '';
        }

        cartItems.forEach(item => {
            const existingCartItem = Array.from(cartContainer.querySelectorAll('.cartlist')).find(cartItem =>
                cartItem.querySelector('.cartname').textContent.trim() === item.productName
            );

            if (existingCartItem) {
                // Update existing item
                const quantityElement = existingCartItem.querySelector('.quantity');
                const cartTotalElement = existingCartItem.querySelector('.carttotal');
                const newQuantity = parseInt(quantityElement.textContent, 10) + item.quantity;
                const unitPrice = parseFloat(cartTotalElement.getAttribute('data-unit-price'));

                quantityElement.textContent = newQuantity;
                cartTotalElement.textContent = `$${(unitPrice * newQuantity).toFixed(2)}`;
            } else {
                // Add new item
                const cartItem = document.createElement('div');
                cartItem.classList.add('cartlist');

                cartItem.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="cartimg">
                        <img src="${item.firstImageSrc}" alt="${item.productName}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="cartdetails">
                        <div class="cartname">${item.productName}</div>
                        <div class="item-description">
                            ${item.selectedColor ? `<p class="color">${item.selectedColor}</p>` : ''}
                            ${item.selectedSize ? `<p class="size">${item.selectedSize}</p>` : ''}
                            ${item.selectedType ? `<p class="type">${item.selectedType}</p>` : ''}
                            ${item.customNote ? `
                                <a href="#" class="show-note">Show Note</a>
                                <p class="note" style="display: none;">${item.customNote}</p>
                            ` : ''}
                        </div>
                        <div class="cartquantity">
                            <span class="minus">&lt;</span>
                            <span class="quantity">${item.quantity}</span>
                            <span class="plus">&gt;</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carttotal" data-unit-price="${item.unitPrice.toFixed(2)}">$${(item.unitPrice * item.quantity).toFixed(2)}</div>
                    <div class="unit-price" style="display: none;">$${item.unitPrice.toFixed(2)}</div>
                `;

                if (cartContainer) {
                    cartContainer.appendChild(cartItem);
                }
                updateCart(cartItem);
            }
        });

        updateSubtotal();
        updateCartCount();
    }

    function updateCartFromLocalStorage(event) {
        if (event.key === 'cart') {
            loadCartFromLocalStorage();
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('storage', updateCartFromLocalStorage);

    function clearCart() {
        document.querySelectorAll('.cartlist').forEach(item => item.remove());
        updateSubtotal();
        updateCartCount();
        localStorage.removeItem('cart');
    }

    const checkoutButton = document.querySelector('.checkout');
    if (checkoutButton) {
        checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', clearCart);
    }

    loadCartFromLocalStorage(); // Load cart items from local storage on page load
});


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Unit Price and Quantity Issues:
The unit price (unitPrice) and the quantities of items were not always correctly updated or retrieved, which could lead to errors in calculating the cart totals.
Synchronization Issues with Local Storage:
Adding or modifying items in the cart might not have been properly saved or retrieved from localStorage, causing a loss of information or desynchronization between views in different tabs or when the page was reloaded.
Incorrect Display of Cart Status:
UI elements, such as the cart item counter, may not have been updated correctly after operations on the cart.
Event Handling and DOM Elements:
Some DOM elements, such as quantity buttons (e.g., .plus and .minus) and product options, required careful event handling to ensure smooth and consistent interactions.
Use of Selectors and Null or Undefined Values:
Accessing certain DOM elements or attributes, such as prices or product selections, needed to be done with proper checks to avoid JavaScript errors (e.g., accessing properties on null elements).
function loadCartFromLocalStorage() {
    const cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];

    const cartContainer = document.querySelector('#popout-cart .carttab');
    if (cartContainer) {
        cartContainer.innerHTML = '';
    }

    cartItems.forEach(item => {
        const cartItem = document.createElement('div');
        cartItem.classList.add('cartlist');
        cartItem.innerHTML = `
            <div class="cartdetails">
                <div class="cartname">${item.productName}</div>
                <div class="cartquantity">
                    <span class="minus">&lt;</span>
                    <span class="quantity">${item.quantity}</span>
                    <span class="plus">&gt;</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carttotal" data-unit-price="${item.unitPrice.toFixed(2)}">$${(item.unitPrice * item.quantity).toFixed(2)}</div>
        `;

        if (cartContainer) {
            cartContainer.appendChild(cartItem);
        }
        updateCart(cartItem);
    });

    updateSubtotal();
    updateCartCount();
} 

function updateCartFromLocalStorage(event) {
    if (event.key === 'cart') {
        loadCartFromLocalStorage();
    }
}

window.addEventListener('storage', updateCartFromLocalStorage);


function clearCart() {
      document.querySelectorAll('.cartlist').forEach(item => item.remove());
      updateSubtotal();
      updateCartCount();
      localStorage.removeItem('cart');
}

